# SearchView suggestionsAdapter.changeCursor() doesn't work outside of onQueryTextChange()

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview, android-cursor

I'm trying to add suggestions to my `SearchView`. To do that I'm using the following `CursorAdapter` as `suggestionsAdapter` for my `SearchView`:

```
cursorAdapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(
    context,
    R.layout.item_search_suggestion,
    null,
    arrayOf(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1),
    intArrayOf(R.id.search_suggestion_text),
    CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER
)
```

Then (to find appropriate suggestions) on `SearchView` query change I call `ViewModel` method to parse data from the server:

```
binding.eventCitySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        viewModel.handleUserIntent(CreateEventIntent.GetCitySuggestions(newText ?: ""))
        return true
    }

})
```

When my `ViewModel` successfuly parses suggestions I update my `cursorAdapter`:

```
private fun updateCitySuggestions(suggestions: List<String>) {
    val cursor = MatrixCursor(arrayOf(BaseColumns._ID, 
    SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1))
    suggestions.forEachIndexed { index, suggestion ->
        cursor.addRow(arrayOf(index, suggestion))
    }
    cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor)
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work. When I type something in the `SearchView` no suggestions appear. I debugged the code and know that `suggestions` in `updateCitySuggestions()` are not empty. So, the problem is not in the `ViewModel`. I also know that if I don't use `ViewModel` and call `changeCursor()` inside the `onQueryTextChange()` using mock data everything works fine.